# How to get the address of an object within that object's class declaration in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am implementing a doubly linked list in C++ and I am trying to add a `node.append(node2)` method to the node class which will link a new node object (node2) to the previous one (node). I receive an `expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token` error on the line `node->previous = Node;`. How do I get the address of the object within its class definition so that I can assign it to `node->previous`?

```
class Node {
    public:
        int value;
        Node *next;//points to next node. 
        Node *previous;//doubly linked list.
        void append(Node *node) {
            next = node;
            node->previous = Node;
            node->next = NULL;
        }
};
```

Comment: You really don't want a node.append(node).  You maybe want list.append(value).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `this` pointer to access the address of your object in C++. Change the line `node->previous = Node;` to `node->previous = this;`.

Comment: Be that as it may, this code can be improved a lot. Why have an append member if you're only using it for one node? Why have a doubly-linked-list type if you're manually allocating nodes? Should you be checking for cycles? How would you do deallocatgion? Why are you including headers from `bits/`? Not even the [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is required :). Here's an equivalent sample: [Live On coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/741dacaea9660ac3)

Comment: @sehe Thank you for your input. I have removed the code which was unnecessary to communicate the question.